# MatLab: Open JPEG binary data as Image

Tags: matlab, encoding, utf-8, windows-1252

I'm running into problems trying to open the binary data I've read into MatLab using fread().
My first approach was saving the image using fwrite(), but MatLab seems to always be defaulting to Windows-1252 encoding, which looses some of the data when writing. (If I open the original input and the output, the content is identical, except for the output missing characters like "ÿØÿà", which obviously means the image is getting corrupted.

I did not find a way to work around this encoding problem.

While I do think this apporach should be working, I also don't really want to write the data to a file before opening it. Just immediately creating an image variable would be preferable. I did not find a solution for doing it this way, though.

My current code:

*Reading the image data*

```
fid = fopen("ente2.jpg",'rb');
bytes = fread(fid);
fclose(fid);
```

*Saving the image*

```
outfile = 'out.jpg';
[fid, msg] = fopen(outfile, 'w', "n","UTF-8");
if fid < 0
  error('Failed to create file "%s" because "%s"', outfile, msg);
end
fwrite(fid, bytes, 'uint32');
fclose(fid);
```

*Opening the image*

```
p = imread(outfile);
figure();
imshow(outfile);
```

Comment: So you have a file `ente2.jpg`, you read in all its bytes, write them out to a new file, essentially creating a copy of the file, then read that copy in using `imread`. Why not directly read in the original file with `imread`? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: If the binary data for the JPEG file comes from elsewhere, you can use a function [such as this one](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53716-decodejpeg) to decode it and produce the raw pixel data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is correct but your implementation has few issues:

- `bytes = fread(fid);` Reads the data as `uint8` elements, but convert the data to class `double`.
  For avoiding the automatic conversion use: `bytes = fread(fid, '*uint8');`.
  Code sample that shows that class is `double`:

  ```
   fid = fopen('football.jpg', 'rb');
   bytes = fread(fid); % The MATLAB default is converting data to class double
   display(class(bytes)) % double
   fclose(fid);
  ```
- When saving the data to file, you should **not** set the encoding.
  Only text files uses encoding.
  You are writing the data into binary file, and binary files are just sequence of bytes (there is no encoding).
  Open a binary file for writing:

  ```
   [fid, msg] = fopen(outfile, 'wb');
  ```
- `fwrite(fid, bytes, 'uint32');` saves `bytes` as type `'uint32'`.
  You need to save `bytes` as `uint8`:

  ```
   fwrite(fid, bytes, 'uint8');
  ```

---

Complete code sample:

```
% Reading the image data
fid = fopen('football.jpg', 'rb');
bytes = fread(fid, '*uint8'); % Use '*uint8' to keep data in uint8 class
display(class(bytes)) % displays uint8
fclose(fid);

% Saving the image
outfile = 'out.jpg';
[fid, msg] = fopen(outfile, 'wb');
if fid < 0
    error('Failed to create file "%s" because "%s"', outfile, msg);
end
%fwrite(fid, bytes, 'uint32'); % Why saving as uint32?
fwrite(fid, bytes, 'uint8');
fclose(fid);

% Opening the image
p = imread(outfile);
figure();
imshow(outfile);
```

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: On Windows it would be good to specify explicitly that one wants to write a binary file: `fopen(outfile, 'wb')`. I'm not sure what the default is, but it's such an important distinction it's good to be explicit about it. On POSIX systems there's no difference between text and binary mode, so the flag is irrelevant there.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am always using `'r'` and `'w'` on Windows, and I can tell that the default is binary. I used to apply `'rb'` and `'wb'` long time ago, but after reading the documentation, I saw that all the examples uses `'r'` and `'w'` (and I started using `'r'` and `'w'`).

Comment: Good to know. I’ve seen quite a few bugs due to wrong b/t mode, hence my comment above. I’ve been happily avoiding Windows for many, many years now, so don’t need to worry about it any more.  :)